# Froze a column inside a pivot table with api sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, pivot-table, google-sheets-api

Do you know how to freeze a column using FrozenColumnCount property (or another), inside a pivot table ?

```
request_body ={
        "requests" : {
            "updateCells" : {
                "rows" : {
                    "values" : [
                        {
                            "pivotTable" : {
                                #Data Source
                                "source" : {
                                    "sheetId": "0",
                                    "startRowIndex" : 0,
                                    "startColumnIndex" : 0,
                                },
                                #Row Field(s)
                                "rows" : [ 
                                    #field 2
                                    {
                                        "sourceColumnOffset" : 5, #Type Preneur
                                        "showTotals" : False,
                                        "sortOrder" : "ASCENDING"
                                    },
                                ],
                                #Columns Field(s)
                                "columns" : [
                                     #Field 2
                                    {
                                        "sourceColumnOffset" : 18, #Année
                                        "sortOrder" : "ASCENDING",
                                        "showTotals" : True
                                    }
                                ],
                                "criteria" : {
                                    6:{
                                        'visibleValues' : ['Solde Créditeur']
                                    },
                                }, 
                                "filterSpecs": [
                                    {
                                        "filterCriteria": {
                                            'visibleValues' : ['Solde Créditeur']
                                        },
                                        "columnOffsetIndex": 6
                                    }
                                ],                                    
                                #Values Field(s)
                                "values" : [
                                    {
                                        "sourceColumnOffset" : 21, #PNS BRUT PPSO
                                        "summarizeFunction" : "SUM",
                                        "name" : ""
                                    }
                                ],
                                "valueLayout" : "HORIZONTAL"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "start": {
                    "sheetId" : id_new_sheet,
                    "rowIndex" : 0,
                    "columnIndex" : 0
                },
                'fields' : 'pivotTable'         
            }
        },
        "properties": {
            "gridProperpties" : {
            "frozenColumnCount": 1,
            }
        } 
    }
```

The pivot table works. I would like to freeze the first column. Here the error message I get :
**Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "properties": Cannot find field.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "properties": Cannot find field.'}]}]">**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- `frozenColumnCount` is for the property of `UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest`. I thought that this is the reason of your issue.
- Property of `requests` is required to be an array.

When these points are reflected in the request body, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified request body:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateCells": {
        "rows": [
          {
            "values": [
              {
                "pivotTable": {
                  "source": {
                    "sheetId": 0,
                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                    "startColumnIndex": 0
                  },
                  "rows": [
                    {
                      "sourceColumnOffset": 5,
                      "showTotals": false,
                      "sortOrder": "ASCENDING"
                    }
                  ],
                  "columns": [
                    {
                      "sourceColumnOffset": 18,
                      "sortOrder": "ASCENDING",
                      "showTotals": true
                    }
                  ],
                  "criteria": {
                    "6": {
                      "visibleValues": [
                        "Solde Créditeur"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "filterSpecs": [
                    {
                      "filterCriteria": {
                        "visibleValues": [
                          "Solde Créditeur"
                        ]
                      },
                      "columnOffsetIndex": 6
                    }
                  ],
                  "values": [
                    {
                      "sourceColumnOffset": 21,
                      "summarizeFunction": "SUM",
                      "name": ""
                    }
                  ],
                  "valueLayout": "HORIZONTAL"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "start": {
          "sheetId": id_new_sheet,
          "rowIndex": 0,
          "columnIndex": 0
        },
        "fields": "pivotTable"
      }
    },
    {
      "updateSheetProperties": {
        "properties": {
          "gridProperties": {
            "frozenColumnCount": 1
          },
          "sheetId": id_new_sheet
        },
        "fields": "gridProperties.frozenColumnCount"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- In this modified request body, `frozenColumnCount` is set to the sheet `id_new_sheet`. If you want to change the sheet, please modify this.
- From `The pivot table works.`, I didn't modify the parameters of `updateCells`.

#### Reference:

- [UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatesheetpropertiesrequest)

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using `batchUpdate` to make requests, the easiest way to accomplish your goal is to make two requests on the same call. To accomplish this, simply transform the `requests` field and make it a list containing your two requests: the `updateCells` and a `updateSheetProperties`.
You can populate the last one with the following:

```py
"updateSheetProperties": {
    "fields":"gridProperties.frozenColumnCount",
    "properties": {
        "sheetId":0, #A 0 if this is the first sheet
        "gridProperties":{"frozenColumnCount":1}
        }
    }
```

You can read more about how those requests are structured [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatesheetpropertiesrequest).